# Resources for Developing SSRS Reports in AX 2009

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-ax-2009

I have spent a lot of time recently looking for some resources to help me to learn some more advanced techniques for developing AX 2009 SSRS reports. There is a lot of information available about making basic reports and Microsoft provides some nice walkthroughs.

What I am looking for is some more in-depth information covering more about writing business logic and methods in C#. Where can I locate some Code samples or even a solid technical book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust you have found the great videos from Saveen Reddy. There are dozen of great videos explaining also into details on how you go about to make AX 2009 SSRS reports:
http://www.youtube.com/user/dynamicsaxbi

Furthermore, I would highly recommend having a look at the already created report libraries. Start off with the libraries ending with SRS (Like CustSRS and VendSRS). Just rightclick a library and choose to edit it in Visual Studio. I assume your environment is already set up for this.

Look into how some reports use queries to collect data directly and some use datamethods. By examining what is already in standard, you can learn a great deal of how to solve your own requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I have one advice to you:
 To develop a neat looking SSRS report, use SharedLibrary already exist project and use its styles.